# Interpreting a Quotient Group ($D_8/\langle r^2\rangle$) in 2 Distinct Ways

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, quotient-spaces

I seem to have a misunderstanding about quotient groups. Let $D_{2n}$ denote the group of symmetries of an $n$-gon and let $V_4$ denote the Klein-4 group. On one hand, if we identify $r^2$ with $1$, we have $$D_8/\langle r^2\rangle=\lbrace 1,r,s,sr\rbrace$$ which is $V_4$.

On the other hand, using the definition of the quotient group as the set of left cosets, $$D_8/\langle r^2\rangle=\Big\lbrace g\lbrace 1,r^2\rbrace :g\in D_8 \Big\rbrace=\Big\lbrace \lbrace 1,r^2\rbrace, \lbrace r,r^3\rbrace,\lbrace s,sr^2\rbrace, \lbrace sr,sr^3\rbrace \Big\rbrace$$

In the latter set, I am not identifying $r^2$ with $1$ since the definition of cosets or quotient spaces does not require me to (by definition, $G/K=\lbrace gK:g\in G\rbrace$). However, none of these elements appears to be the identity, and the second entry squared, $\lbrace r^2,r^2\rbrace$, doesn't even belong to the set. Where am I going wrong? Is one allowed to replace $r^2$ with 1 in the latter approach?

**EDIT**: $D_8=\langle r,s:r^4=s^2=1, rs=sr^3\rangle$, so $r$ denotes the rotation and $s$ denotes the reflection.

Comment: Your $r$ is the rotation of order 4 in $D_8$, right?

Comment: Yes, I will edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when multiplying two *complexes* (subsets) $A,B \subset G$ the result is:
$$
AB=\{ab|a \in A,b \in B\}
$$
so for your problem case:
$$
\{r,r^3\}^2 = \{rr,rr^3,r^3r,r^3r^3\} =\{r^2,1,1,r^2\}=\{1,r^2\}
$$

Comment: In general, can one replace $r^2$ with $1$ in the latter case and avoid any trouble? That is, can I identify $r^2$ with $1$ in either approach?

Comment: @TheSubstitute if you identify $r^2$ with $1$, then the coset $\{r, r^3\}$ collapses to $\{r\}$, since $r^3 = r^2r \approx 1r = r$. The trick is, and why we need NORMAL subgroups, is to ensure this collapsing doesn't "mess up" our multiplication-we need this to know that for two cosets $A,B = xN, yN$ for our subgroup $N$, that the *product set* $AB$ (as in David Holden's answer) is another coset of the form $zN$. This is so we can define a binary operation on the set of cosets.

Answer (score 1):

The subgroup $\langle r^2\rangle$ is normal in $D_8$ because $r^2$ is in the center:

For an element $g \in G,\; gr^2g^{-1}=gg^{-1}r^{-2}=r^{-2}=r^2 \in \langle r^2\rangle$.

Since the subgroup is normal, the set of cosets becomes a group with the following operation:

$$a\langle r^2\rangle b\langle r^2\rangle = ab \langle r^2\rangle \; \forall a,b \in D_8$$

This group has identity $\langle r^2\rangle$ because $\langle r^2\rangle=1\cdot\langle r^2\rangle$, so $$a\langle r^2\rangle\cdot \langle r^2\rangle=a\cdot 1\langle r^2\rangle = a\langle r^2\rangle$$

for any coset $a\langle r^2\rangle \in D_8/\langle r^2\rangle$.

I'm not sure of how exactly you derived the isomorphism with $V_4$ in your first interpretation, since $r^2$ is not an element of $D_8/\langle r^2\rangle$, but the isomorphism can be justified with the group in the second interpretation.

The easiest way to see the isomorphism is to show every nonidentity element has order 2:

$$\{r,r^3\}^2=\langle r^2\rangle \text{ (David Holden's answer shows this)}\\
\{s,sr^2\}^2=(s\langle r^2\rangle)^2=s^2\langle r^2\rangle=\langle r^2\rangle \\
\{sr,sr^3\}^2=(sr\langle r^2\rangle)^2=(sr)^2\langle r^2\rangle=srsr\langle r^2\rangle=ssr^{3}r\langle r^2\rangle=\langle r^2\rangle$$

Comment: In the first interpretation, I identified $r^2$ with $1$, which is in the quotient group.

Comment: But $r^2$ is not in the quotient group, which consists of cosets of $\langle r^2\rangle$, not elements of $D_8$. Or am I misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: Ah, as sets they are not equal, but both sets are isomorphic to the Klein-4 group. Since $r^2=1$ in my first interpretation, $r^2$ corresponds to $\lbrace 1,r^2 \rbrace$ in the latter set. My follow up question is whether I am allowed to replace $\lbrace 1,r^2\rbrace$ with $\lbrace 1,1\rbrace$ and if the resulting set will always be isomorphic to the original.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense. So you derived the first interpretation by introducing that relation and computing the multiplication table? or...?

Comment: I know that each element of $D_8$ is of the form $s^xr^y$ where $x=0,1$ and $y=0,1,2,3$. In each of these elements I replaced $r^2$ with 1 and simplified to get the 4 elements $1,r,s,sr$. You can also do this by introducing the relation $r^2=1$ into the multiplication table, but I didn't explicitly use the table.

Comment: They should be, because then $\{1,r^2\}=\{1,1\}=\{1\}, \{r,r^3\}=\{r,r\}=\{r\}, \{sr,sr^3\}=\{sr,sr\}=\{sr\}$, and $\{s,sr^2\}=\{s,s\}=\{s\}$. Then you can show these also have order 2. Then you're actually looking at the cosets of $\{1\}$, I think.

Comment: Thanks, I assume this works in any setting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26007/discussion-between-coldnumber-and-the-substitute).